# use constant defined on parent module inside child module's configuration

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have `main` angular module which knows about server url and I set it like this:

```
angular.module('main', ["editor"]).constant("main.serverUrl", "http://serverurlhere.com")
```

I also have `editor` module on which `main` module depends. `Editor` module knows controller name (`editor`) on server it talks to, but doesn't know the serverUrl, so I want to use the `serverUrl` constant inside `editor` module to define `editor.serverUrl` constant something like this:

```
angular.module('editor').constant("editor.serverUrl", main.serverUrl + "/editor")
```

How can I do that?

**UPDATE:**

```
var m = angular.module("main", ["editor", "mainModuleProviders"]);
var mProviders = angular.module("mainModuleProviders", []);
mProviders.constant("serverUrl", "http://someserverurl.com");

var e = angular.module("editor", ["mainModuleProviders"]);
e.config(["serverUrl", "$provide", function(serverUrl, $provide){
  $provide.value("editor.serverUrl", serverUrl + "/editor/")
}]);
```

Comment: you can configure your constant in [`config` block](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/module#Configuration-Blocks)

Comment: yeah, but the problem is that `main.serverUrl` constant is not available yet when config block of `editor` module is being executed since `main` module depends on `editor` module.

Comment: can you provide some jsfiddle or plunkr? what you try

Comment: @Grundy, [here is the plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/w3SHIb0J1IQ3CtrIVpsu?p=preview). As you can see the `serverUrl` from `main` module is not available inside `config` function of `editor` module.

Comment: but in plunker you use _value_ instead _constant_

Comment: well, if you change it to constant - `m.constant("serverUrl", "http://someserverurl.com");` - [it's the same thing](http://plnkr.co/edit/w3SHIb0J1IQ3CtrIVpsu)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try something like this

```
var e = angular.module("editor", [])
               .constant("editor.url", "/editor");

var m = angular.module("main", ["editor"]);
    m.constant("serverUrl", "http://someserverurl.com");


m.config(["editor.url","serverUrl", "$provide", function(eu,se,$provide){
  $provide.constant("editor.serverUrl",se+eu);
}]);
```

```js
var e = angular.module("editor", [])
  .constant("editor.url", "/editor");

var m = angular.module("main", ["editor"]);
m.constant("serverUrl", "http://someserverurl.com");


m.config(["editor.url", "serverUrl", "$provide",
  function(eu, se, $provide) {
    $provide.constant("editor.serverUrl", se + eu);
  }
]);

e.controller('ctrl', ["$scope", "serverUrl", "editor.url", "editor.serverUrl",
  function($scope, su, eu, seu) {
    $scope.serverUrl = su;
    $scope.editorUrl = eu;
    $scope.editorServerUrl = seu;
  }
])
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="main" ng-controller="ctrl">
  <div>serverUrl = {{serverUrl}}</div>
  <div>editorUrl = {{editorUrl}}</div>
  <div>editorServerUrl = {{editorServerUrl}}</div>
</div>
```

**UPDATE**
In AngularJS used dependency injection, so when you add dependency in your module it must be loaded before this module run.
In your first variant: you try use main module that depend on editor module inside editor modue.
For solving you can use third module from your second variant *mainModuleProviders*, or configure all inside main module.

***NOTE***: inside angular does not have module, so no matter where declared this constant

Comment: Thanks, it's working! I'm just curious why the previous variant didn't work and this one works? Do you mind elaborating a bit?

Comment: I've also come up with [this solution](http://plnkr.co/edit/w3SHIb0J1IQ3CtrIVpsu?p=preview), can you comment anything about it?

Comment: hm, link to your solution not work, can you add code to your post?

Comment: @Maximus, try see my updated answer, possibly now it more clear

Comment: yeah, thanks. So which option would you choose: yours with two constants or mine with additional module?

Comment: @Maximus, methinks, one addtional module with _all_ constants better.

Comment: where can I read more about your comment `inside angular does not have module` ?

Comment: yeah, but it doesn't mention there that there are no modules internally

Comment: i mean when you load all dependency in main module, you work only with main, and use loaded services and providers, but if you have two services with same name in two different module, then after resolve dependency you have only last loaded

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/73577/discussion-between-grundy-and-maximus).